# LinearLayout inside TableRow does not respect gravity assigned

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am trying to add a `LinearLayout` inside a Table Row `programmatically`. The linear layout is centered in gravity in the XML. But it shows on the left of the table row as shown below

The `TableLayout` is defined below:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SELECT A VEHICLE"
        android:textColor="@color/select_vehicle"
        android:id="@+id/select_vehicle"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSearchResultTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/select_vehicle_table"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/select_vehicle"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the linear layout that is a child view of a table row :

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_name"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Vehicle Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_number"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Vehicle Number" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the way i am setting it programmatically, but the centered gravity is not showing up:

```
 mTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.select_vehicle_table);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {

            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.END));
            tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_border);


            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row_linear_layout,null);
            TextView vehicle_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_name);

            vehicle_name.setText(vehicle_name_array[i]);
            TextView vehicle_number = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_number);
            vehicle_number.setText(vehicle_number_array[i]);

            tableRow.addView(v);
            mTableLayout.addView(tableRow);
        }
```

Comment: Where you want to show Textviews? horizontally center or vertically center ?

Comment: horizontally centered

Comment: Make Textview's width to `wrap_content` and check

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. Anyways i got it. just setGravity of tableRow outside the setLayoutParams like this : tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

Answer (score 1):

I just missed this line of code while setting the LL programmatically

```
tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```